# The X Axis labels doesnt show in LineChart (MpAndroidChart)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mpandroidchart, linechart

I have a simple linechart where the values of X correspond to the months of the year. The problem is that he does not show me the corresponding labels. I use an IAxisFormatter to replace the month's numbers with the text (1 = Jan, 2 = Feb, etc ...)

[image: This is how it looks now]

But, i want it to look this

[image]

I put the code of how I have configured the line chart (Kotlin)

```
    // GENERAL CONFIGURATION
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.setPinchZoom(false)
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.setTouchEnabled(false)
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.description = null
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.legend.isEnabled = false
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.axisRight.isEnabled = false
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.xAxis.valueFormatter = MonthFormatter()
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.isDragEnabled = true
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 315f
    lineChartEvolucionFragment.xAxis.setDrawLabels(true)

    // DATASET
    val entries = mutableListOf<Entry>()

        for (historia in getHistoryDummy()) {
            val month = Funciones.formatTimestamp("MM",  historia.fechaEnviado).toIntOrNull()
                    ?: continue
            entries.add(Entry(month.toFloat(), getDatoByType(historia)))

            Log.d(TAG, "Mes: ${month.toFloat()}")
        }

        val dataset = LineDataSet(entries, "Evolución")
        dataset.lineWidth = 2f
        dataset.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.colorAccent)
        dataset.setCircleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
        val lineData = LineData(dataset)
        lineData.setValueFormatter(ValueFormatter())
        lineData.setValueTextSize(12f)
        lineChartEvolucionFragment.data = lineData

        lineChartEvolucionFragment.axisLeft.addLimitLine(getLimitByType())
        lineChartEvolucionFragment.setVisibleXRange(1f, 5f)

        lineChartEvolucionFragment.animateX(500, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInSine)

    //FORMATTER

    class MonthFormatter : IAxisValueFormatter {

    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String =       when  (value) {
    1f -> "Jan"
    2f -> "Feb"
    3f -> "Mar"
    4f -> "Apr"
    5f -> "May"
    6f -> "Jun"
    7f -> "Jul"
    8f -> "Aug"
    9f -> "Sept"
    10f -> "Oct"
    11f -> "Nov"
    12f -> "Dec"
    else -> ""
       }

    }
```

Im using the version 3.0.3

Comment: Post your layout xml code. Also, provide missing kotlin code if possible.

Comment: Can you public full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should work :

```
var xAxis = lineChartEvolucionFragment.xAxis
xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
xAxis.setDrawLabels(true)

var xLabels = lineChartEvolucionFragment.xLabels
xLabels.setPosition(XLabelPosition.BOTTOM)

xAxis.valueFormatter = MonthFormatter()
```

I suspect `float value` of `1` will return `1.0f`, you are checking `1f`. So, edit your value formatter :

```
class MonthFormatter : IAxisValueFormatter {
override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String =       
    when (Math.round(value)) {
        1 -> "Jan"
        2 -> "Feb"
        3 -> "Mar"
        4 -> "Apr"
        5 -> "May"
        6 -> "Jun"
        7 -> "Jul"
        8 -> "Aug"
        9 -> "Sept"
        10 -> "Oct"
        11 -> "Nov"
        12 -> "Dec"
        else -> ""
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set lableCount for as many mounth you want to show and check if that fixes your problem.

```
lineChartEvolucionFragment.xAxis.lableCount = 12
```